# Extract string with multiple criteria - sql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

We have a column of varying string values like below.  How to extract part of the string and return the desired result in Redshift?

Example

1. Remove last part that starts with an underscore and number (_1_MN, number can be 1-1000)
2. Remove leading part (Ed_)
3. Replace any remaining underscore with a space

String:
Ed_Westside Ind School District 94_Williams Elementary School_1_MN

Desired result:
Westside Ind School District 94 Williams Elementary School

Comment: postgresql <> redshift. please remove the postgresql flag

Answer (score -1):

MySQL

```
UPDATE products 
SET col = SUBSTRING(col FROM 3)
WHERE col LIKE ('Ed_%')

UPDATE products 
SET col = SUBSTRING(col FROM -5 )
WHERE col LIKE ('%_1_MN')

UPDATE products 
SET col = REPLACE(col, '_', ' ')
```

Comment: Thanks, alsaleem.  Is there a postgresql version that would work in Redshift and without using update?

Comment: WHERE col LIKE ('%_1_MN') will not work as every ending number and letters are different.

Comment: This is not a MYSQL question.

Answer (score -1):

While not very elegant, this worked.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(LEFT(RIGHT(name, LEN(name) - 3), LEN(name) -8) , '_', ' ')
```

Comment: I think this works only in the example given, but not if the number is >10